# How to shift the data from one cell to another cell in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

I am using MS Excel 2010 and I want as I type any value or word in the A1 cell, it should automatically be transferred into D1 cell and A1 cell should get blank again. Similarly if I type any value or word in A2 cell then it should automatically be transferred into D2 cell and A2 cell should get blank again and so on.

Please suggest me any way, formula or VBA coding to do that. Someone suggested me the following VBA codes to shift the values but these codes are working only for the A1 cell. Namely these codes can shift the value of A1 cell to D1 cell only but I want the entire column A to work as I want.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = ActiveSheet
theRow = Target.Row
theColumn = Target.Column
theValue = Target.Value
If theRow = 1 Then
If theColumn = 1 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    wks.Cells(1, 4) = theValue
    Target.Clear
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Offset(0, 3).Value = Target.Value
        Target.Clear
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```